How are listener methods in antlr4 are being called if root rule does not reference all rules in grammar?
For example, my grammar is:
File met.g4: 
grammar met;

import b;

dateInterval: startdate=DATE DASH enddate=DATE;

met : data=ID COMMA dateInterval;


File b.g4:

grammar b;

etc…

My test input includes the input for the root rule and all other rules specified in my grammar. What I observe is that the tokens are generated for rule “met” but not for other rules. Listener method is only being called on rule "met", but not for other rules, even though input text matches other rules. I don’t understand why, can somebody explain it to me? Thanks!

What is your root rule? If dateInterval is your root rule, then met will never be triggered of course.

My root rule is met; but my input includes the text for all rules. I think that what you imply is that the root rule should include references to all other rules. Correct?

Your start rule is erroneous. You must add EOF to the end of a start rule. Otherwise Antlr will stop parsing on an error.
